# Can i use distinctUntilKeyChanged for removing duplicate objects?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7, rxjs6

I'm new to rxjs in Angular 7 , i have an api that returns the user details.I want to remove objects that are having same name,i hardly tried it using distinctUntilKeyChanged() but getting output in console as same as from the api response. and also can i directly use returned data  from service as the responce is already a Observable using Interface without using From() or 0f() in component.

This is for angular 7 and Rxjs 6 , i have been using angular for one year but i didnt used Rxjs till now,am getting lots of confusions in Rxjs, that can i use the Http response from service directly in component or else do i want to use any operators for converting the response as stream in brief can i use the Json responce directly in component for using different operators like find(),first(),ignoreElements etc...

user.service.ts

```
  private urlLara = 'http://laravel.technalatus.com/public/api/'
  public getusers(): Observable<User> {
    const head = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
    return this.http.get<User>(this.urlLara + 'users', { headers: head 
    });
  }
```

component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'angularrxjs';
  items: {};
  post: Post;
  user: User;
  public searchTerm: string;

  constructor(private UserService: UserService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.distinct()
  }

  public Duchanged() {
    // custom compare for name
    this.UserService.getusers().pipe(distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.name === curr.name))
      .subscribe(console.log);

  }
```

Getting output as

```
[
{id: 2, name: "alshoja", email: "alshoja@gmail.com", email_verified_at: null, type: "admin"},
{id: 3, name: "Ellaware", email: "abhi@gmail.com", email_verified_at: null, type: "user"},
{id: 17, name: "alshoja", email: "c@g.com", email_verified_at: null, type: "user"}
]
```

Expecting Output as

```
[
{id: 2, name: "alshoja", email: "alshoja@gmail.com", email_verified_at: null, type: "admin"},
{id: 3, name: "Ellaware", email: "abhi@gmail.com", email_verified_at: null, type: "user"},
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of how `distinctUntilKeyChanged` and `distinctUntilChanged` works is incorrect. As per the docs

> - `distinctUntilKeyChanged` only emits when the specified key value has changed. (Source: [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilkeychanged.html))
> - `distinctUntilChanged` only emits when the current value is different than the last. (Source: [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html))

Since in each object the `name` changes from the last object, it will emit each time. In your case, `distinctUntilKeyChanged` or `distinctUntilChanged` will only work if your "distinct" items are in order like below

```
[
  { id: 3, name: "Ellaware", email: "abhi@gmail.com", email_verified_at: null, type: "user" },
  { id: 2, name: "alshoja", email: "alshoja@gmail.com", email_verified_at: null, type: "admin" },
  { id: 17, name: "alshoja", email: "c@g.com", email_verified_at: null, type: "user" }
]
```

You can use `distinct` instead

```
import { distinct, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

public Duchanged() {
  this.UserService.getusers()
  .pipe(
    distinct(user => user.name),
    toArray()
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Comment: Do you realise your answer is incomplete? The result of the distinct pipe is single objects. Not an array.

Comment: i got your point @nash11, can i directly use the returned responce in component by the way it came from service? if can help , it ill be nice

Comment: @Carsten - My bad, he mentioned in his question that he was getting an array as his output so I assumed was doing that. I have updated my answer

Comment: @EducDevTeam - check out the updated answer to see how to get the output as an array.

Comment: @nash11, got the answer as an array but the array contains duplicate name, may be my bad

Comment: @EducDevTeam this answer is correct. Minimal test results in what you want. (from(this.test).pipe(distinct(a => a.name), toArray()).subscribe(console.log);) (this.test being your array).

Comment: @Carsten, i want avoid the duplicates in the result but am getting the same result as it come from Api , Sorry my question is about "remove objects that are having same name"

Comment: @EducDevTeam Then you're doing something wrong.. The answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

`distinctUntilChanged` operator will ignore new results from the stream which are exactly the same, here u have a stream with only one result on it which is the array of users.

What you should do is use the `map` operator and use arrays `filter` to remove duplicates from your array.

```
this.UserService.getusers().pipe(
   map((users) => users.filter((v,i) => users.indexOf(v) === i))
   .subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
distinctUntilChanged -> It will check only current and prev object.Before passing the JSON ,You should sort based on name then use distinctUntilChanged();
the result of this.UserService.getusers() should be like this:
[
{id: 2, name: "alshoja", email: "alshoja@gmail.com", email_verified_at: null, type: "admin"},
{id: 17, name: "alshoja", email: "c@g.com", email_verified_at: null, type: "user"},
{id: 3, name: "Ellaware", email: "abhi@gmail.com", email_verified_at: null, type: "user"}
```